# trouble with evaluation in binding expression in Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, data-binding

Here is the expression:

```
ClientID='<%# Eval("MedicationName") + "@" + Container.DataItemIndex %>'
```

I am trying to assign an id to a control in a gridview.
MedicationName is a property of the data source. I would like the result of this to be `id="Aspirin@0"`

Comment: The given code is works as expected for me. Is there any problem?

Comment: @SelvaTS yes, it is telling me that no MedicationName@0 property exists on the binding object

Comment: Possible post your Data source here.

Comment: @SelvaTS Thanks for the response. I will post it when I get to my work machine =]